# How to set `footskip` on a landscape page?

Tags: header-footer, margins, geometry, landscape

I'm using `geometry` and `pdflscape` to have a *particular page* in landscape ([detailed here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Margins.2C_page_size_and_rotation_of_a_specific_page)).

However, setting `footskip` via `\newgeometry{..., footskip = 1cm}` does nothing, because the system still assumes the `footskip` margin is along the short edge of the paper as if were a portrait page.

So how to adjust `footskip` on a landscape page?

Comment: Without a full MWE this won't get answers I'm afraid: as it stands, it's 'unclear'.